# GIT tree messed up after unaware amending — needs reordering/cleaning

Tags: git

For the record I'm using `git` to maintain my electronics projects with [gEDA](http://www.geda-project.org/) suite. My current project has two branches, *rev-A* and *rev-B*. I'm currently working upon revision B. I recently noticed I had made mistakes in my old revision A (wrong revision number in schematics and PDF file) so I fixed the two documents and amended the changes using `git reset -hard <ID>` and `git commit -a --amend`.

I did such edits twice but I was unaware of the precautions I had to take with those changes — I mean I think I messed up the history and now the tree doesn't quite look what I want/expect it to.

Here's what the tree looks like after amending commits (`--date-order` gives the same result):

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
* 35945e5 (rev-A) Revision A - Final product
| * aada926 (HEAD -> rev-B) Revision B - Updated BOM (...)
| * b88eb61 Revision B - Final product as ordered (...)
| * 0bda52b Revision B - Reduced to 25.4mm x 35mm
| * fe2246f Revision A - Final product
|/  
* 260eb65 Revision A - Smaller capacitor footprint (...)
```

Here's the tree with all the commits I made (`--date-order` gives the same result):

```
$ git log --reflog --graph --oneline --decorate
* 86d6072 Revision A - Smaller capacitor footprint (...)
* 35945e5 (rev-A) Revision A - Final product
| * aada926 (HEAD -> rev-B) Revision B - Updated BOM (...)
| * b88eb61 Revision B - Final product as ordered (...)
| | * 7ba0df4 Revision B - Final product as order (...)
| |/  
| * 0bda52b Revision B - Reduced to 25.4mm x 35mm
| * fe2246f Revision A - Final product
|/  
* 260eb65 Revision A - Smaller capacitor footprint (...)
```

With `git diff` I could notice the following:

- commits **b88eb61** and **7ba0df4** show no change, obviously `7ba0df4` is redundant (it's even the one commit I wanted to get rid of since it has a typo in the message)
- between **260eb65** and **86d6072**, the latter is the one I'd like to keep
- between **fe2246f** and **35945e5**, the latter is the one I'd like to keep

Here's the branches I have:

```
$ git branch
  rev-A
* rev-B
```

Apart from that I'm not sure I understand both trees, especially as to where the branch name appears. What I want is all of my *Revision A* commits belong to branch `rev-A` and all the *Revision B* to `rev-B`. How can I safely reorder and tidy up that tree?

**EDIT**: After further analysis, I deduce commit `86d6072 Revision A - Smaller capacitor footprint (...)` is lost somewhere while it's the one from which revision B should be forked instead of `260eb65`. So how can I have it back into the `rev-A` branch and replace `260eb65`

Comment: What _specific_ commits did you reset to and amend? Where are they in your tree?

Comment: @Useless That's where I get lost. From my bash history, I did reset to `86d6072` and amend from there, then reset to `35945e5` and amend from there as well. Strangely enough those are the commits that contain the documents I need to keep. I don't understand anything anymore and I didn't unfortunately take note of the change ID's, I'm sorry.

Comment: According to you description, `260eb65` and `86d6072` should be _siblings_, but your graph shows the newer version as the ancestor of the old. It's very hard to figure out what could have happened from your description, because this is literally impossible. Perhaps you could remove the `--date-order` and include the last common ancestor in your tree?

Comment: @Useless It looks like the last common ancestor between `rev-A and `rev-B` is `260eb65`. I also found out there's no difference whether I use `--date-order` or not.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard :` is a very lethal command, is potentially dangerous since it throws away all your uncommitted changes. For safety, you should always check that the output of `git status -s` is clean (that is, empty) before using it.

Still it's not that easy to follow unless until following reflog commands, do use `git reflog`

> `git reflog,`  Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of
>   branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

One thing you can do if you didn't push your changes to the remote origin is [squash the redundant commits](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-how-to-squash-multiple-git-commits). So yes, `git rebase` will do that trick of reordering the commit. Example to reorder the last two commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

For a more complex example:

```
$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      B
      C
```

If you want to reorder B with C:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
pick 1f9133d B
pick 33f41be C
```

You just re-order them to be:

```
pick 33f41be C
pick 1f9133d B
```

After your done writing, see the shortlog:

```
$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      C
      B
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm only using local repositories. I also made sure I had committed all my pending changes beforehand so I lost nothing. Well, I found out I lost my `HEAD` but I could find it back with my latest commit so I restored its position, if I may say so. I also guess from your response `git rebase` is what I need to reorder my commits, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not able to edit the text as code in comment, that's why I posted new answer.

Oh yes, git rebase will do that trick of reordering the commit. Example to reorder latest two commits, git rebase -i HEAD~2.

```
$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      B
      C
If you want to reorder B with C:

$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
pick 1f9133d B
pick 33f41be C
You just re-order them to be:

pick 33f41be C
pick 1f9133d B
After your done writing, see the shortlog:

$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      C
      B
```

Comment: «*Not able to edit the text as code in comment*» Ah, that, I can help ;-) . I now merged both your answers. You can safely delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for more than 2 days, I took a shortcut: I have now completely erased my GIT tree (i.e. `rm -rf .git`) after backing up revisions A and B in a tarball archive. There are now only 2 commits instead of 4-5 but it's fine as it's only a local repository.

The true solution still remains to be found but I'm at a noob's end. Took me less time to scrap it all and build it anew than all of my unsuccessful attempts at understanding what to do, I admit but I can't afford spending more time on it.

Comment: I have a backup of the "old" GIT tree so further attempts remain possible, just in case...